# Scheduling Azure Worker Role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-scheduler

I am writing a small azure worker role that remove old files from my Azure-Storage account. 
I am planning to run this code *one time per month*. The duration of task execution is less the 10 minutes.

What I'm planning is to run this worker role and when it's finish - stop the worker role (aka quit). Now, I want to schedule another task that will start my worker role *every first day in month*.

**Solution 1:** While reading [this article](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/using-quartz-net-to-schedule-jobs-in-windows-azure-worker-roles/), I found the Quartz library not suitable because my worker role is running for the whole month (and I keep paying).

**Solution 2:** I saw it possible to use Azure-Queues to start my first instance of the application while some message in the queue. But, this is too much things to handle, while the task itself is pretty easy. Looking for more easy solution.

Any better solution? Maybe Azure-Worker-Role is not suitable for this task?

Answer (score 3):

A Worker Role may not be the best choice for this task. You have two alternatives that might be better:

1. Use an Azure WebJob instead of a Worker Role. WebJobs support scheduling.
   http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/
2. Use the Azure Scheduler.
   http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Comment: Adding to Richard's answer, you may also want to look into Azure Automation as well: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/.